# Adding jlabel to a jframe using components

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

I have 2 classes,

My main class creates a frame and I want another class to add content to it. A bit of reading arroudn told me I should use components to do this however when I run my code the frame is empty.

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    // create frame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    final int FRAME_WIDTH = 800;
    final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 600;
    // set frame attributes
    frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    frame.setTitle("My Frame");
    frame.setVisible(true);

    Component1 Com = new Component1();
    Component add = frame.add(Com);

}
```

My Component class creates a JLabel

```
public class Component1 extends JComponent {

   public void paintComponent()
   {
       JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>Some Text</html>");
   }
}
```

I don't get any compile errors, however I dont get any text in my JFrame.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Chris

Comment: Where are you adding your JLable?

Comment: `public class Component1 extends JComponent {

   public void paintComponent()
   {
       JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>Some Text</html>");
   }
}`  Use a `JLabel` instance instead.  Give it text of "" at start-up.  Set a text later and it will become visible.  As a general tip though, don't create objects in ..I was about to say `paintComponent(Graphics)` except that doesn't have one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to *add* the `JLabel`. Also better to extend `JPanel` instead of `JComponent` as it has a default [layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) and will make any added components appear without the need to set component sizes. `paintComponent` is used for custom painting BTW.

```
public class Component1 extends JPanel {

   Component1() {
      JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>Some Text</html>");
      add(label);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No need to create a new `Component`. Just call `frame.getContentPane().add(label)`. And initialize your label before this.